# TimedRotatingFileHandler not working with dictconfig

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing

This is how I am reading configuration from my configuration file

```
config.dictConfig(final_config_file)
```

This is my configuration.json file.

```
{
  "logging": {
    "version": 1,
    "root": {
      "handlers": [
        "file_handler"
      ],
      "level": "DEBUG"
    },
    "disable_existing_loggers": false,
    "handlers": {
      "file_handler": {
        "class": "logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler",
        "formatter": "json",
        "when": "midnight",
        "backupCount": 0,
        "filename": "C:/Users/desaijb/Desktop/gitpractice/log.json"
      }
    },
```

I am using timedrotatinghandler to rotate file as day changes but somehow it did was not working and I am unable to change the file as per time. I have set it on midnight but it was not working.Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

Set "backupCount" to nonzero. To understand it, read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler):

> If backupCount is nonzero, at most backupCount files will be kept, and if more would be created when rollover occurs, the oldest one is deleted. The deletion logic uses the interval to determine which files to delete, so changing the interval may leave old files lying around.

I hope it will help you.